# Stored procedure increasing performance

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, t-sql, stored-procedures

I wrote a stored procedure that does exactly the same as my Visual Basic .NET code. Now I have benchmarked them both. Using a while loop and a for loop. But both gave me way more terrible results that using my Visual Basic .NET code. Is there any way to improve the performance of this code:

```
DECLARE @RelationCode nvarchar(50)
DECLARE @CompanyName nvarchar(256)
DECLARE @IncomingInvoice decimal(18, 2)
DECLARE @OutgoingInvoice decimal(18, 2)
DECLARE @Profit decimal(18, 2)
DECLARE @RelationTable as TABLE (RELATIONCODE nvarchar(10), COMPANY nvarhar(120))

INSERT INTO @RelationTable (RELATIONCODE, COMPANY) SELECT [fms].[dbo].[Relation].[RELATIONCODE], [fms].[dbo].[Relation].[COMPANYNAME] FROM [fms].[dbo].[Relation]

/* Result table */
DECLARE @RESULTTABLE TABLE (RelationCode nvarchar(50), Companyname nvarchar(256), IncomingInvoice nvarchar(50), OutgoingInvoice nvarchar(50), profit nvarchar(50))

WHILE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @RelationTable)
BEGIN
SELECT TOP 1 @RelationCode = RELATIONCODE, @CompanyName = COMPANY FROM @RelationTable

    SELECT fmsTotalAmountIncoming INTO TempIncomingAmounts FROM (
            SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN fms1.currency != 'EUR'
                THEN fms1.amount * fms1.rate
            ELSE ISNULL(fms1.amount, 0) END) fmsTotalAmountIncoming
    FROM [fms].[dbo].[file] f
        INNER JOIN [fms].[dbo].[incominginvoiceline] fms1 ON 
       fms1.filenumber = CONVERT(NVARCHAR, f.filenumber)
    WHERE f.RELATIONCODE = @RelationCode
    ) a 

    SELECT fmsTotalAmountOutgoing INTO TempOutgoingAmounts FROM (
            SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN fms1.currency != 'EUR'
                THEN fms1.amount * fms1.rate
            ELSE ISNULL(fms1.amount, 0) END) fmsTotalAmountOutgoing
    FROM [fms].[dbo].[file] f
        INNER JOIN [fms].[dbo].[outgoinginvoiceline] fms1 ON 
       fms1.filenumber = CONVERT(NVARCHAR, f.filenumber)
    WHERE f.RELATIONCODE = @RelationCode
    ) a 
    SET @IncomingInvoice = (SELECT fmsTotalAmountIncoming FROM [fms].[dbo].[TempIncomingAmounts])
        SET @OutgoingInvoice = (SELECT fmsTotalAmountOutgoing FROM [fms].[dbo].[TempOutgoingAmounts])
        SET @Profit = ((@OutgoingInvoice - @IncomingInvoice) / @OutgoingInvoice)

        INSERT INTO @RESULTTABLE ([RELATIONCODE], [CompanyName], [IncomingInvoice], [OutgoingInvoice], [Profit])
                VALUES (@RelationCode, @CompanyName, @IncomingInvoice, @OutgoingInvoice, @Profit)

        DROP TABLE [fms].[dbo].[TempIncomingAmounts]
        DROP TABLE [fms].[dbo].[TempOutgoingAmounts]

        DELETE FROM @RelationTable WHERE RelationCode = @RelationCode
    END

    SELECT * FROM @RESULTTABLE
```

I have benchmarked this, results below:

```
STORED PROCEDURE        VB.NET
6:54                    5:11
6:20                    5:11
6:19                    3:55
6:43                    4:01
```

Does anyone have any clue on how to raise the performance above the VB.net performance, because this way the stored procedure is kind of useless.

Comment: Stored procedures *don't* improve performance of bad queries. Instead of using cursors or loops like this (actually an even slower form of cursor) you should write a proper query

Comment: Please post your table schema and an example of your data.

Comment: Use right tool for the job. Sql server is just IO device which designed for saving and reading data. Calculations and other "business" logic can be done in your application (`vb.net`) - much easy, can be done faster(`async-await` approach for loading data from different tables), readable(very important) and easy to maintain.

Comment: @Fabio classic developer attitude there. The argument between business logic in code and business logic in SP's rages on. You can call a SP async. You definitely want to do joins, lookups, sorts on large recordsets in the database, not in the app layer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to replicate procedural VB code in SQL. SQL is set-based and only performs well on that basis. Without knowing exactly what your schema is, this is the roughly what your SQL should look like to get the results you require much, much quicker:

```
;
WITH invoice (RELATIONCODE, COMPANYNAME, IncomingInvoice, OutgoingInvoice)
AS (
    SELECT r.[RELATIONCODE], r.[COMPANYNAME], 
    SUM(CASE WHEN fms1.currency != 'EUR'
            THEN fms1.amount * fms1.rate
        ELSE ISNULL(fms1.amount, 0) END) AS IncomingInvoice, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN fmso.currency != 'EUR'
            THEN fmso.amount * fmso.rate
        ELSE ISNULL(fmso.amount, 0) END) AS OutgoingInvoice
    FROM [fms].[dbo].[Relation] r
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [fms].[dbo].[file] f
    ON f.RELATIONCODE = r.[RELATIONCODE]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [fms].[dbo].[incominginvoiceline] fms1
     ON fms1.filenumber = CONVERT(NVARCHAR, f.filenumber)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [fms].[dbo].[outgoinginvoiceline] fmso
     ON fmso.filenumber = CONVERT(NVARCHAR, f.filenumber)
     GROUP BY r.[RELATIONCODE], r.[COMPANYNAME]
 )
 SELECT RELATIONCODE, 
    COMPANYNAME, 
    IncomingInvoice, 
    OutgoingInvoice,
     CASE WHEN OutgoingInvoice > 0 THEN (OutgoingInvoice - IncomingInvoice) / OutgoingInvoice 
    ELSE 0 END AS Profit
 FROM invoice
```

i.e. no loops, if...else statements, creation, deletion and then recreation of permanent tables etc. Just one SQL statement that groups your results by relationcode and companyname.

Comment: This works and is quite fast, but it kills itself when it divides by zero, how to eliminate that? I am getting this: 
https://gyazo.com/3d31bacdb4f26a67e61fe027bacf8c6a

Comment: I've added a `CASE` statement in the `SELECT` to check for 0 values in the denominator which will avoid the divide by 0 exception.

Comment: Well it works, but i have a lot of rows missing, i have 4474 relations, and it gives me back 1707 rows, a lot of relations don't have incoming or outcoming invoices, how to still get them? even if they are NULL

Comment: @ThimoFranken you haven't provided the schema or an example of the data so you can't expect perfect results. How can anyone guess which fields are nullable and which not?. strickt01 has done a remarkable job rewriting the loop into a query

Comment: A `LEFT JOIN` to `file` should do it although without knowing the exact schema it's impossible to know. The concept though should be clear. I've rewritten it using a CTE too which makes the profit calculation cleaner. You should also probably add some `ISNULL`s into the `SELECT` where appropriate (i.e. on columns of tables you are `LEFT JOIN`ing to.

Comment: @ThimoFranken, out of interest what is the benchmark for this stored procedure?

Comment: 3 seconds for about 164k records ;)